# Texmaker - Remove the toolbar shortcut buttons

Tags: texmaker

As we all know it, Texmaker has those shortcut buttons on the vertical toolbars which generate some latex code. These are of no use to me and I want to remove them.

[image: shortcut_buttons]

I have tried to read the [Texmaker's user manual](https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html) to figure it out by myself but I could not find a solution so maybe someone has found it or I might be just missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the horizontal toolbar by right-clicking it. This will let you remove most of the latex-shortcuts, but not all.

[image: Configure horizontal toolbar]